# What's the Next number in series #1?

Tags: number-sequence

Can you find the next number in the below sequence

```
 3 , 7 , 10 , 11 , 12 , 17 ?
```

Note: if already asked please comment below, as I've searched for this but not found on this site so that I posted it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The next number is

> 20

This is because the sequence refers to numbers which:

> Only contain the vowel 'e'
> Eg. thr**ee**, s**e**v**e**n, etc.
> Thirteen does not qualify because it contains an i, for example.

Comment: one could argue that 'y' is a vowel

Comment: don't the numbers thirteen through nineteen contain 2 e's each, or more?

Comment: @JLee ONLY contain the vowel e. No other vowels

Comment: ok i see now. thx